# Fast report FRXdbdataseet filter Error

Tags: mysql, delphi, report, delphi-xe8, fastreport

I am Using Delphi RAD x8 and fast report to generate report.
I have no issue if i do a general filtering 
I generate daily report base on datetime field.

```
with frxDBDataset1.GetDataSet do begin
      close;
      open;
      Filter:='tanggal_berobat = '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('yyyy-mm-
      dd',DateTimePicker1.date));
      Filtered := True;
     end;
    Frxreport1.ShowReport();
```

And the issue come with this code(i use month and year function on filtering).
I want to generate monthly report based on datetime field.

```
with frxDBDataset2.GetDataSet do
 begin
 close;
 open;
 Filter:='month(tanggal_berobat)='+quotedstr(ComboBox1.Text)+'and year(tanggal_berobat)='+quotedstr(ComboBox2.Text);
 Filtered := True;
 end;
Frxreport2.ShowReport();
end;`
```

with given error : "argument are the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another."

Is there another or alternative way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: The `Filter` property doesn't support DBMS functions. And even if it was, you could not compare ordinal results of `MONTH` and `YEAR` against constant strings which is what you do by the `QuotedStr` function. But you can build a fully qualified date time from what you have and use `>=`, `<=` operators. If you were using FireDAC, you could do that. P.S. there's no need to reopen dataset, just disable and enable the filter.

Comment: Also you can use filter for TfrxMasterData or show/hide TfrxMasterData band in the TfrxMasterData.OnBeforePrint event